# Convert Curl -G to java code

Tags: java, curl

I need to transform this curl to java code

```
curl -G \
-u "{user}":"{pass}" \
-d "version=2018-03-16" \
-d "the msg" \
-d "features=entities" \
-d "entities.model={modelID}" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze"
```

and my java code is something like that

```
URL url = new URL(uri.toString()); 
HttpURLConnection handle = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String userpass = "{user}:{pass}";
new Base64();
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userpass.getBytes()));
handle.setRequestMethod("POST");
handle.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
handle.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
handle.setRequestProperty("version", "2018-03-16");
handle.setRequestProperty("text", params.getParameterString());
handle.setRequestProperty("features", "entities");
handle.setRequestProperty("entities.model", wksModel);
handle.setDoOutput(true);
```

This gives me error 400 so you do not know where my mistake, I hope you can help me

Comment: your curl send request where all -d params are attached to the url like in GET request (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G), so instead handle.setRequestProperty I would add them after '?' to the url

Comment: Does the body of the 400 response give any clue what the problem is?

Comment: you're using post with java, and get with curl, if the url you're requesting does not support post your code will not work, and please post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because we cannot check what's going on with what's posted as some information is missing